# Format date with StringFormat in TextBlock in WPF

Tags: wpf, textblock, string-formatting

I have stored date in database without slashing for some reason . it means that I have a date field like 20110602.

As i want to retrieve this date and show it in a textblock I need a formatting to show this date as a normal date with slash.

How can i use StringFormat in this way ? ... does anyone konw what format should I use to convert "20110602" to 2011/06/02 ?

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding CreatedDate, StringFormat=?????"
```

Comment: Update your database, do not do it on the client. StringFormat won't help you anyway, but you might use converter

Comment: I have to do it because i'm using Persian Date Time .. and i don't have equivalent control either in UI nor I have this type in Sql server ...  and I NEED a formatter to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you perfer the route of implementing a converter:

```
class dateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string dateString = (string)value;
        return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=<path>, Converter={StaticResource <dateTimeConverterKey>}, StringFormat=\{0:yyyy/MM/dd\}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the DateTime.ParseExact method:

```
  dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
  format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
  try {
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```

in your case i believe that the format should be:

```
 format = "yyyyMMdd";
```

for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much introducing this method but I want to use this formatter in a Binding .. so i need a way to do it in Xaml not in C#

Comment: Couldn't get it from your question before it was edited... sorry that i couldn't help