# How to get short date format in my Textbox WPF

Tags: wpf, datepicker, textbox

I have my table DataType is set to `Date` in SQL Server but is showing the `DateTime` in my WPF textbox and I'm not sure how I can format the textbox or SQL Server to only show `Date`.

I tried using `DatePicker` instead of a `TextBox` but I need it to be ReadOnly and the `DatePicker` is grayed out when it is set to NOT ENABLED and there is no option for ReadOnly.

How can I only display the short date in my `TextBox`?

Comment: Set the format property to the format you want. For example `yyyy-MM-dd` for something like `2020-04-11`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format date with StringFormat in TextBlock in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971620/format-date-with-stringformat-in-textblock-in-wpf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088998/custom-date-format-for-textbox

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should solve your problem:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyPath, StringFormat=d}" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm trying to bind the selected cell from a date column titled `OPENED` the following line of code opens the new window and displays the cell from in the row selected from the `DataGrid` `windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = row_selected["OPENED"].ToString();`